# Getting 404 Not Found on OPTIONS with NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, cors, http-options-method, nestjs

I'm new to NestJS and on every route my web app is trying to query, it fails on the OPTIONS request, getting:

> {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Cannot OPTIONS
>   /authenticate"}

however trying a direct GET or POST request works fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

after some researches I've realised that I simply needed to [enable CORS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security) (Access-Control-Allow-Origin), which I can do by editing my `main.ts` and passing `cors: true` to the `NestFactory.create` options (second parameter).

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: The cors is a built-in feature, see here for more details: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cors :)

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec This still doesn't work for me. Neither does app.enableCors(). All HTTP OPTIONS requests just fail with a 404. Not sure what's wrong

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec where did the CORS documentation go on the nestjs documentation site? it appears there is a redirect now

Answer (score 11):

Some extra info on CORS, if you enable it via:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

This will allow Cross Origin Requests from any domain. Which is generally not security best practice.

If you want to allow CORS to intercept your preflight requests, but also only allow origin requests from within the server, you can use this config:

```
.....
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {cors: {
    origin: true,
    preflightContinue: false,
  }});
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone still looking for the answer

```
app.enableCors();
```